# The message count I'm getting from Google API differs in approx. 10% from what I see on Gmail

Tags: python, email, google-api, gmail-api

I'm using Python to connect to my Gmail account through `Gmail API`.

When running the code in the [example on Google Developers website](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#examples) — the message count I'm getting from `Google API` differs in approximately 10% from what I see on [Gmail](http://gmail.com) (under `All Mail` tab), even if I add the trashed mails to the calculation.

Do you know what might be the cause?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you see in Gmail UI will be total number of conversations, not messages unless you [turn conversation mode off](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense now.